# Stroke Paint default activation

Tags: color, inkscape, fonts, stroke

I have to enumerate hundreds of cables for a project but every time I write something `Stroke paint` is activated

[image]

The problem is that Inkscape draws the text automatically with `stroke` and without a `fill`

For me it is impossible to have to remove `stroke paint` and insert a `fill color` every time, it is a *waste of time*.

Is there a method to change this default? Or to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set some text with a black fill, and no stroke.
2. Make sure the text is is selected
3. Do *Edit > Preferences > Tools > Text*
4. In the options select "This tool's own style". Then hit "Take from Selection"

[image]